# Mysql ssl connection from remote server

Tags: mysql, ssl

I have a mysql-server set up on one server. I have enabled SSL by adding the following lines into the [mysqld] section in my.cnf:

```
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
```

I have generated these certificates by following the steps in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/creating-ssl-certs.html

Now on the same server when I run the mysql client with the following command, the connection is established with SSL enabled:

```
mysql -uuser -p --ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem
```

Now when I try to do the same from a remote server

```
mysql -uuser -hserver.asdf -p --ssl-ca=ca-cert.pem
```

, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error
```

where in I have copied the same ca-cert.pem file that i used previously. But when I run the following command, the connection gets established with SSL enabled:

```
mysql -uuser -hserver.asdf -p --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl-key=client-key.pem
```

From what I can understand, --ssl-cert and --ssl-key parameters are required in the mysql client command only if we want the server to authenticate the client and are not actually necessary. But why is it that I can connect when I use these parameters and not otherwise?

**UPDATE**

There were certain other important factors that I thought were unimportant during the time of asking this question. The mysql-server package version being used was Percona-Server-51-5.1.73 and the mysql-client package on the local server was Percona-client-51-5.1.73. But on the remote server the mysql-client package was Percona-client-51-5.1.61

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there were some major changes made with respect to Percona-mysql packages with respect to SSL in the more recent builds of Percona-mysql. All older builds of the percona-mysql package came with yaSSL support whereas more recent builds use OpenSSL.

This was  done because packages with yaSSL builds apparently used to cause some programs to crash. More details regarding this bug can be found here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/+bug/1104977

Since this issue was fixed from 5.1.68 onwards, obviously a package before that didn't function properly.

So after updating the mysql client package to the latest version, the problem was fixed.